# Can't find strings on x64 dbg

Tags: x64dbg

I can't find strings from message boxes.

**Questions:**

1. How do i find the strings?
2. What are these strange symbols?
   [image]
3. Is it possible to transform them into readable ones? how?

**Detailed information:**

1. I open the exe file on exeinfoPE (see picture).
   [image]
2. x64dbg don't show error messages from textboxes when i search them into strings.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. ResourceHacker don't show tables (just informing).
   [image: ResourceHacker]

Purposes and other:

1. I am trying to crack this program.
2. I'm newbie in this journey - like 1 week, not much progress.

Answer (score 2):

1. 

You can put a breakpoint on the 'MessageBox' syscall, and inspect it's arguments.
From the MSDN the arguments are:

> int MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);

And you are interessted in 'lpText':

> The message to be displayed. If the string consists of more than one line, you can separate the lines using a carriage return and/or linefeed character between each line.

You can do this by doing the following:

- Open your file in x64dg, and in the command prompt at the bottom type 'bp MessageBox'. You can also break on 'MessageBoxA', 'MessageBoxW', 'MessageBoxExA', 'MessageBoxExW', 'MessageBoxIndirectA' and 'MessageBoxIndirectW'
- Run your binary (first 'run' bring you to the entrypoint, second one run the program).
- Deal with any exceptions or condition in order to go to the part of the code that displays your message box.
- When you break on one of the message box API, press 'return to user code' in order to inspect the application's code, and not the message box API itself.
- Finally you can inspect which arguments where passed to that function
- When you see the second argument ('lpText'), right clic on it, 'follow in memory dump' and you should see the message you are viewing !

2. Those are not strings. What you are seeing is a bunch of pointers to the header of your program. Take a look at your binary header. You will see the magic byte 'MZ' at the start. x64dg think this is a string, but it's not.
3. Oh, and by the way, you are looking at an 'AutoHotKey' binary. Make some research on how to reverse this. It is a by different than usual.

Comment: Regarding your top bullet point: wouldn't you even _have_ to set a breakpoint on individual functions rather than `MessageBox`? Also, it's not a syscall by a long shot.